# throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I use from socket.io and nodejs with express. i have this error :

`throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');`

i use from

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.3.6",
    "socket.io": "0.9.16",
    "jade": "~0.35.0",
    "less-middleware": "~0.1.12",
    "redis": "~0.8.4",
    "connect-redis": "~1.4.5",
    "longjohn": "~0.2.1",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.20"
```

and

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

how i can fixed this problem?

Comment: This is often caused by trying to change/set response headers when you have already send something across the response stream. You can try to find the places that headers are set/modified and see if there are any response sent between them. Or try removing modules and packets one by one to see which modules is causing the issue.

Comment: Or just post some code. Also, the traceback generated usually provides a clue where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are setting the headers of a http response after sending it. In my experience that usually means that you're replying twice at the same request. Or, in your case, maybe incorrect middleware order.

If you're only using static routes should be a middleware problem. Try to remove either packages or express middlewares. They should be somehow incompatible.

Also, as other asked, post some traceback or code so others can help you better.